# btrfs - cloning a file - how works copy-on-write?

Tags: btrfs

I have a btrfs volume which I use for backups.

It is almost full (few MB free).
If I duplicate a (big, too big for the existing free space on the volume) file, it works. That is expected since btrfs is a copy-on-write fs.

```
cd /btrfs-backup/
cp /home/john/a.mp4 . # 1st instance of the file takes place on the volume.
cp a.mp4 b.mp4        # 2nd instance does not take place and is immediate.
```

But if I copy that same file from the source fs, it fails:

```
cp /home/john/a.mp4 c.mp4 # 3rd instance of the same file.
cp: error writing 'a.mp4': No space left on device
```

Why that error?

Should not the same file be made of the same blocks, which should not be duplicated on btrfs fs?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to have a look at the [BTRFS documentation about CoW](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Copy_on_Write_.28CoW.29) and some [use cases](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/UseCases#How_do_I_copy_a_large_file_and_utilize_COW_to_keep_it_from_actually_being_copied.3F).

For short, in order to prevent duplication, the data (meaning, the two files) must be on the same filesystem.

The filesystem must have CoW support, and you need to *not* have the `+C` flag on the source file (cf `man chattr`).

The `cp` command also need to know that it must use CoW, with the `--reflink` option (cf `man cp`).

CoW should be enabled by default on your system, but depending on your setup things may be different.